# Can the main method invokeLater be created differently than it normally is in a Java main method?

Tags: java

Can the invokeLater be coded so that you can create an instance of Runnable and then @Override the method run() and then send that Runnable variable into the method.

I am wanting to see if you can change how the code is generated and still get the same results because that is how I start figuring out how things really work in a programming language.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class DDHSimpleProgram {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("A simple Swing Program");
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Swing powers the modern GUI!");

    public DDHSimpleProgram() {
        f.setLocation(300, 300);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(l);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void run() {
        new DDHSimpleProgram();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = null; 
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

This code works:

The code below works with the program implementing the Runnable interface and then creates the GUI in the zero argument constructor. The invokeLater creates a new instance of the object as an anonymous class. The Run method actually does not do anything other than write a message to the console. I still think that this is an interesting part of the object oriented design structure that seems odd to me sometimes still because you can actual have the method to anything you want it to do.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class DDHSimpleProgram implements Runnable {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("A simple Swing Program");
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Swing powers the modern GUI!");

    public DDHSimpleProgram() {
        f.setLocation(300, 300);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(l);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run Method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DDHSimpleProgram());
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this question. I always like to see if there are other ways of writing the same code. I think that guy has a good point here, and that is to see if this can be done a different way other than the same old standard way that in many cases is created by the Eclipse GUI editor.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do this.

This is because you set the Runnable to null, insert that into SwingUtilities but all SwingUtilities will know about is null. That is because Java objects are passed by value (pointer value), and therefore you can't change what you already set to null in SwingUtilities.

Also that code is likely to throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: How could this be done though. I set the pointer to null because it will not compile it it is not null. Is there a way to change that and set it to call the Run() method of the Runnable interface.

Answer (score 2):

The first example won't work, `r` is `null`. The reason it won't come is because your class does't implement `Runnable`, so `run` can never be called by `invokeLater`

The second example constructs the UI class outside of the EDT but calls `run` either the EDT via `invokeLater`

Preferrably, I would construct a `Main` class that `implements Runnable`. From its main method, I would construct an instance of `Main` and pass it as a reference to `invokeLater`. In the `run` method, I would go about constructing the UI, but I'm fussy this way

> Can the invokeLater be coded so that you can create an instance of
>   Runnable and then @Override the method run() and then send that
>   Runnable variable into the method.

The answer to that is, yes.  Any instance of an object that implements `Runnable` can be passed to `invokeLater`

**Updated with example...**

Based on the assumption of the main interface looking like...

```
public class DDHSimpleProgram {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("A simple Swing Program");
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Swing powers the modern GUI!");

    public DDHSimpleProgram() {
        f.setLocation(300, 300);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(l);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I might use a `Main` class something like...

```
public class Main implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Main());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DDHSimpleProgram prog = new DDHSimpleProgram();
    }

}
```