# Menu Bar not appearing in Java

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, menu

I made and defined my menu bar with all it's variables and It just plain won't show up. It compiles well and runs easily but the menu bar just isn't there... Did I place it in the wrong place?
   Fyi: The menu bar is near the top of the code and there are some checkboxes near the bottom which were added to the menu bar.

[image: GUI]

```
        import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import json.JsonObject;
public class dicebot extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static JCheckBox RollAmntCheck;
    public static JTextField txtRollAmnt;
    public static String APIKey = null;
    public static JComboBox<String>cmbCurrency;
    public static JMenuBar menuBar;
    public static JMenu menu;
    public static JMenuItem menuItem;
    public static JButton btnLow;
    public static JButton btnFloat;
    public static JButton btnHigh;
    public static JButton btnClearLog;
    public static JButton btnDonate;
    public static JButton btnCalc;
    public static JCheckBox AlwaysOnTopCheck;
    public static JCheckBox scrollCheck;
    public static JCheckBox scrollDisable;
    public static JTextField txtUserName;
    public static JTextField txtStartBid;
    public static JTextField txtMultiplier;
    public static JTextField txtMinRemaining;
    public static JPasswordField txtPassword;
    public static JTextField txtOdds;
    public static JTextField txtMaxBet;
    public static JTextArea txtInfo;
    public static JLabel lblBalTag;
    public static JLabel userTag;
    public static JLabel passTag;
    public static dicebot frame = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame = new dicebot();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                    Dicebotcode d = new Dicebotcode();
                    d.LoadSettings();
                    //d = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public dicebot() {
        setTitle("Dice Bot");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        contentPane.add(menuBar);

        menu = new JMenu("Options");
        menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Menu Bar");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Menu");
        menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Menu");
        menu.add(menuItem);



        //Every new Label however needs every part that says "user" or on the Password: "pass" changed to something unique.
        userTag = new JLabel("Username:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_userTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_userTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_userTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_userTag.gridx = 0;//Here are your x + y coords
        gbc_userTag.gridy = 1;//Adding to x moves left, adding to y moves down
        panel.add(userTag, gbc_userTag);

        //Every new textfield needs only the * part to change for it to be valid. (gbc_* =)
          //textField = new JTextField();
        txtUserName = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdUserName = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdUserName.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdUserName.gridx = 1;
        grdUserName.gridy = 1;
        txtUserName.setColumns(10);
        panel.add(txtUserName, grdUserName);
        //panel.add(textField,txtUserName);
        //textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel balTag = new JLabel("Current Balance:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_balTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_balTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_balTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_balTag.gridx = 0;  
        gbc_balTag.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(balTag, gbc_balTag);

        lblBalTag = new JLabel("[________________]");
        lblBalTag.setToolTipText("Balance as of the last call to the peerbet site.");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblBalTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblBalTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_lblBalTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_lblBalTag.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblBalTag.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(lblBalTag, gbc_lblBalTag);

        JLabel startTag = new JLabel("Starting Bid:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_startTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_startTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_startTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_startTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_startTag.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(startTag, gbc_startTag);

        txtStartBid = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdStartBid = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdStartBid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdStartBid.gridx = 1;
        grdStartBid.gridy = 3;
        txtStartBid.setText("0.00000010");
        txtStartBid.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtStartBid, grdStartBid);

        JLabel multTag = new JLabel("Multiplier:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_multTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_multTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_multTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_multTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_multTag.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(multTag, gbc_multTag);

        txtMultiplier = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdMultiplier = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdMultiplier.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdMultiplier.gridx = 1;
        grdMultiplier.gridy = 4;
        txtMultiplier.setColumns(10);
        txtMultiplier.setText("2");
        txtMultiplier.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtMultiplier, grdMultiplier);

        JLabel minTag = new JLabel("Min Remaining:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_minTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_minTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_minTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_minTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_minTag.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(minTag, gbc_minTag);

        txtMinRemaining = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdMinRemaining = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdMinRemaining.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdMinRemaining.gridx = 1;
        grdMinRemaining.gridy = 5;
        txtMinRemaining.setColumns(10);
        txtMinRemaining.setText("0");
        txtMinRemaining.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtMinRemaining, grdMinRemaining);

        txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
        GridBagConstraints grdPassword = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdPassword.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdPassword.gridx = 1;
        grdPassword.gridy = 2;
        txtPassword.setEchoChar('*');
        txtPassword.setColumns(10);
        panel.add(txtPassword, grdPassword);

        passTag = new JLabel("Password:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_passTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_passTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_passTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_passTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_passTag.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(passTag, gbc_passTag);

        txtOdds = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdOdds = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdOdds.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdOdds.gridx = 1;
        grdOdds.gridy = 6;
        txtOdds.setColumns(10);
        txtOdds.addActionListener(this);
        txtOdds.setText("49.5");
        txtOdds.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtOdds, grdOdds);

        JLabel oddsTag = new JLabel("Odds %:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_oddsTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_oddsTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_oddsTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_oddsTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_oddsTag.gridy = 6;
        panel.add(oddsTag, gbc_oddsTag);

        txtMaxBet = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdMaxBet = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdMaxBet.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdMaxBet.gridx = 1;
        grdMaxBet.gridy = 7;
        txtMaxBet.setColumns(10);
        txtMaxBet.setText("1");
        txtMaxBet.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtMaxBet, grdMaxBet);

        //This is the Combo Box
        cmbCurrency = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"BTC","LTC","PPC","NMC","XPM","FTC","ANC","DOGE","NXT"});
        GridBagConstraints gbc_list = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_list.gridx = 1;
        gbc_list.gridy = 9;
        cmbCurrency.addActionListener(this);
        cmbCurrency.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(cmbCurrency, gbc_list);

        JLabel maxTag = new JLabel("MaxBet:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_maxTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_maxTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_maxTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_maxTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_maxTag.gridy = 7;
        panel.add(maxTag, gbc_maxTag);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        txtRollAmnt = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdRollAmnt = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdRollAmnt.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdRollAmnt.gridx = 1;
        grdRollAmnt.gridy = 8;
        txtRollAmnt.setColumns(10);
        txtRollAmnt.setText("0");
        //txtRollAmnt.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtRollAmnt, grdRollAmnt);

        RollAmntCheck = new JCheckBox("Quit on win after:");    
        RollAmntCheck.setSelected(true);
        GridBagConstraints grdRollAmntCheck = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdRollAmntCheck.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdRollAmntCheck.gridx = 0;
        grdRollAmntCheck.gridy = 8;
    panel.add(RollAmntCheck, grdRollAmntCheck);

        AlwaysOnTopCheck = new JCheckBox("Always On Top");  
        AlwaysOnTopCheck.setSelected(false);
        AlwaysOnTopCheck.addActionListener(this);
        GridBagConstraints grdAlwaysOnTopCheck = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdAlwaysOnTopCheck.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdAlwaysOnTopCheck.gridx = 0;
        grdAlwaysOnTopCheck.gridy = 9;
        menu.add(AlwaysOnTopCheck, grdAlwaysOnTopCheck);

        btnDonate = new JButton("Login");
        btnDonate.addActionListener(this);
        panel_1.add(btnDonate);

        btnHigh = new JButton("Roll High");
        btnHigh.addActionListener(this);
        btnHigh.setEnabled(false);
        panel_1.add(btnHigh);

        btnLow = new JButton("Roll Low");
        btnLow.addActionListener(this);
        btnLow.setEnabled(false);
        panel_1.add(btnLow);

        btnFloat = new JButton("Roll Float");
        btnFloat.addActionListener(this);
        btnFloat.setEnabled(false);
        btnFloat.setVisible(false);
        panel_1.add(btnFloat);

        btnClearLog = new JButton("Clear Log");
        btnClearLog.addActionListener(this);
        panel_1.add(btnClearLog);

    btnCalc = new JButton("Max Loss Streak");
        btnCalc.addActionListener(this);
    btnCalc.setEnabled(false);
        btnCalc.setVisible(true);
        panel_1.add(btnCalc);

        scrollCheck = new JCheckBox("Auto-Scroll"); 
        scrollCheck.setSelected(true);
        menu.add(scrollCheck);

        scrollDisable = new JCheckBox("Disable Log");   
        scrollDisable.setSelected(false);
        menu.add(scrollDisable);

        btnCalc.setToolTipText("Click here to calculate the max loss streak you can handle based on current imputs.");
        btnClearLog.setToolTipText("Click here to clear the log!");
        btnHigh.setToolTipText("Click here to Roll High!");
        btnLow.setToolTipText("Click here to Roll Low!");
        btnFloat.setToolTipText("Click here to Roll?");
        scrollCheck.setToolTipText("Toggles the auto-scroll function of the log.");
        txtMaxBet.setToolTipText("The dicebot will not bet above amount entered in.");
        txtOdds.setToolTipText("What odds(%) will the dicebot be rolling?");
        txtPassword.setToolTipText("Enter your peerbet account password.");
        AlwaysOnTopCheck.setToolTipText("Click to have the bot always appear above other windows");
        txtMinRemaining.setToolTipText("The bot will stop when account has less than this amount in bank.");
        txtMultiplier.setToolTipText("What shall the bet be multiplied by upon loss?");
        txtStartBid.setToolTipText("What amount should the bot start each bet at?");
        txtUserName.setToolTipText("Enter your peerbet account username.");
        lblBalTag.setToolTipText("Current amount of chosen currency shown here.");
        cmbCurrency.setToolTipText("Choose the currency that the bot will be using to roll with.");
        txtRollAmnt.setToolTipText("Number of times to roll before stopping. 0 = Infinite");
        RollAmntCheck.setToolTipText("Select to stop only after a win. Unselect to stop as soon as the # of rolls is reached");

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();//   JScrollPane scrollPanel1 = new JScrollPane();//This will hold the information the bot sends over such as win/loose or error
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        txtInfo = new JTextArea("All number formats must use a period(.)\n");
        txtInfo.setColumns(35);
        txtInfo.setEnabled(false);
        txtInfo.setDisabledTextColor(Color.black);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(txtInfo);

        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == cmbCurrency) {
            if (cmbCurrency.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
                txtStartBid.setText("0.00000010");
            }else{
                txtStartBid.setText("0.0001");
            }
            if(APIKey != null){
                String balance = peerbetapi.get_balance(dicebot.APIKey);
                JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(balance);
                if(jsonObject.get("status").asInt() == 1){
                    lblBalTag.setText(jsonObject.get("raffle_cur" + Integer.toString((cmbCurrency.getSelectedIndex() + 10))).asString());
                }
            }else{
                lblBalTag.setText("[________________]");
            }
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnLow){
            if(btnLow.getText() == "Roll Low"){
                btnHigh.setText("Stop");
                btnLow.setText("Stop On Win");
                btnFloat.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode dbc = new Dicebotcode();
                Dicebotcode.RollType = "low";
                Dicebotcode.StopRollingOnWin = false;
                Dicebotcode.StopRolling = false;
                dbc.dbc();
            }else{
                // The EnableAllFields function will re-enable the buttons once its done.
                btnLow.setText("Waiting...");
                btnLow.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode.StopRollingOnWin = true;
            }
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnHigh){
            if(btnHigh.getText() == "Roll High"){
                btnHigh.setText("Stop");
                btnLow.setText("Stop On Win");
                btnFloat.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode dbc = new Dicebotcode();
                Dicebotcode.RollType = "high";
                Dicebotcode.StopRollingOnWin = false;
                Dicebotcode.StopRolling = false;
                dbc.dbc();
            }else{
                // The EnableAllFields function will re-enable the buttons once its done.
                btnHigh.setText("Stopping...");
                btnHigh.setEnabled(false);
                btnLow.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode.StopRolling = true;
            }
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnFloat){
            if(btnFloat.getText() == "Roll Float"){
                btnHigh.setText("Stop");
                btnLow.setText("Stop On Win");
                btnFloat.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode dbc = new Dicebotcode();
                Dicebotcode.RollType = "float";
                Dicebotcode.StopRollingOnWin = false;
                Dicebotcode.StopRolling = false;
                dbc.dbc();
            }else{
                // The EnableAllFields function will re-enable the buttons once its done.
                btnFloat.setText("Stopping...");
                btnFloat.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode.StopRolling = true;
            }
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnClearLog){
            txtInfo.setText("");
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnDonate){
            //donate d = new donate();
            if(btnDonate.getText() == "Login"){
                String reply = null;
                try {
                    reply = peerbetapi.login(txtUserName.getText(), String.copyValueOf(txtPassword.getPassword()));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    reply = "{\"status\":0, \"message\":\"An unknown error has occurred while attempting to login.\"}";
                }
                JsonObject json = JsonObject.readFrom(reply);
                if(json.get("status").asInt() != 1){
                    txtInfo.append("Error: " + json.get("message").asString() + "\n");
                    txtInfo.setCaretPosition(txtInfo.getText().length());
                }else{
                    APIKey = json.get("key").asString();
                    lblBalTag.setText(json.get("raffle_cur" + Integer.toString(cmbCurrency.getSelectedIndex() + 10)).asString());
                    btnDonate.setText("Donate");
                    userTag.setVisible(false);
                    txtUserName.setVisible(false);
                    passTag.setVisible(false);
                    txtPassword.setVisible(false);
                    txtStartBid.setEnabled(true);
                    txtMultiplier.setEnabled(true);
                    txtMinRemaining.setEnabled(true);
                    txtOdds.setEnabled(true);
                    txtMaxBet.setEnabled(true);
                    cmbCurrency.setEnabled(true);
                    btnHigh.setEnabled(true);
                    btnLow.setEnabled(true);
                    btnFloat.setEnabled(true);
                    txtInfo.append("Login successful!\n");
                    txtInfo.setCaretPosition(txtInfo.getText().length());
                }
            }else{
                donate.showdonate();
            }
        }else if(e.getSource() == AlwaysOnTopCheck){
            if(AlwaysOnTopCheck.isSelected() == true){
                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            }else{
                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set the frames menu bar, something like...

```
frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

Also, `static` is not your friend. If you find yourself needing to make fields `static`, it's likely you've done something wrong

Instead of building your UI within the `main` method, I would create a "main" class whose responsibility is to build the UI and show the main window, this would mean you can get out of the `static` context of the `main` method

You could take a look at [Can the main method invokeLater be created differently than it normally is in a Java main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215914/can-the-main-method-invokelater-be-created-differently-than-it-normally-is-in-a/24216105#24216105) for an example

**Updated**

Two things...

First, follow the advice that has been given, don't add the `JMenuBar` to the content pane, set it as the `JFrame`s menu bar...

```
menuBar = new JMenuBar();
//contentPane.add(menuBar);
setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

Second, don't add components to the menu bar, this is not how it works

```
//menu.add(AlwaysOnTopCheck, grdAlwaysOnTopCheck);
```

Take the time to read through [How to use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) to better understand how they work

Comment: What should i swap static with?

Comment: Nothing, for the most part, the fields could be set up as instance fields

Comment: one of the checkboxes shows up as the bar and I wanted that to be the thing that says Options

Comment: Then use a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` and add it to the `Options` `JMenu`